# How do I save oauth2 token in a docker volume?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, docker, google-oauth, docker-volume

I am quite new to docker, aws and google api.
I want to create a small service in aws that converts a list of data into a google sheet.

I have an issue with the authentication part on a container. I figured that I would need a volume to save the credentials in. I am able to save files to a volume from the program, but I want to save a folder with credentials to the volume. The google api opens a browser if I run it locally, but that won't work in the container.

How do I save the credentials folder to a volume in the docker file or docker compose? 
How do I access the folder from the program?

**Test program Code**

```
class Program
{
    static string[] Scopes = {SheetsService.Scope.Spreadsheets, DriveService.Scope.Drive};
    static string ApplicationName = "SheetsApiTest";
    static string path = @"/var/lib/docker/volumes/test_vol/_data/createdfromprogram2.txt";
    static string basePath = @"/var/lib/docker/volumes/test_vol/_data/";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       UserCredential credential;
       credential = UserCredential();

        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("File exists :) ");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Creating file");
            File.Create(path);
        }
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

**The Docker file**

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:3.1 AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["SheetsApiTest.csproj", "./"]
RUN dotnet restore "./SheetsApiTest.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "SheetsApiTest.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "SheetsApiTest.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .

#What I want to to get copied.
COPY token C:\credentials\testcred\.
VOLUME /var/lib/docker/volumes/test_vol/_data

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "SheetsApiTest.dll"]
```

**Docker compose**

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  sheetsapitest:
    image: sheetsapitest
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes: 
     - test_vol:/var/lib/docker/volumes/test_vol/_data

volumes: 
  test_vol: {}
```

Comment: Does it need to be written to disk? I'd say retrieve it via an API if you possibly can, then write locally in Docker volume (but not persist to the underlying host disk space. If you're using AWS try looking at secrets manager or systems manager parameter store

Comment: To get the oauth2 token from the google api it opens the browser to get authentication from the credentials, then it creates the token as far as i understood. My plan was to get the token on the disk first, then copy it to the volume. think it also needs to edit the token in the volume for the refresh token. I might be mistaken tho.I will check out secrets manager, thanks!